# Append A Value To The Existing Value In SQL, facing error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table in which there is a column name associated_ids with datatype as varchar2(4000). It contains a value and i need to append the new value with existing value. Using below update query:

```
update ncl_getafix.service_graph 
set Associated_ids = Associated_ids + ',' + '95d4980b-d12c-4854-97c6-bd9854f8f003' 
where SERVICE_ID='075d7a58-7fad-4e1d-9822-83a2fa1a0d05';
```

I am getting below error:

> Error starting at line : 5 in command - update
> ncl_getafix.service_graph set
> Associated_ids=Associated_ids+','+'95d4980b-d12c-4854-97c6-bd9854f8f003'
> where SERVICE_ID='075d7a58-7fad-4e1d-9822-83a2fa1a0d05'
> Error report - ORA-01722: invalid number.

Can anyone help to debug this.

Comment: Have you tried using CONCAT? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need to use concat operator `||` not `+` as follows:

```
update ncl_getafix.service_graph 
set Associated_ids = Associated_ids || ',' || '95d4980b-d12c-4854-97c6-bd9854f8f003' 
where SERVICE_ID='075d7a58-7fad-4e1d-9822-83a2fa1a0d05';
```

Answer (score -2):

i found the answer.

Use || symbol instead of + in query